# Scientific Work Place 6.0 problem of pdf compilation

Tags: languages, scientific-workplace

I have just bought and installed Scientific Workplace 6. To gain time, I have translated my french file (sci) into english using google translate by now I can not compile the text into PDF file... It is as if he can not recognize english words...too strange. Is there anybody who can explain this?
regards
jfj

Comment: isn't a sci file basically tex? if you translate the english tex commands into french they will not work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  in version 6.0, SW changed to XML as the basic format to save the document in. That is why I never upgraded, I am still using 5.5, which works well and I will never change to 6.0.  I was told it is possible to explicitly ask SW to export to Latex from XML. I do not know how well this works.

Comment: Try to ask this at SW forum. They have one at http://forum.mackichan.com/  I doubt many here use V 6.0 of SW.

Comment: @Nasser it must go to latex in the end to typeset.